# How to run Powershell scripts in vb.net using WorkingDirectory and shellExecute = false

Tags: vb.net, powershell, process

I need to run a PowerShell script in vb.net application with Alternate user credentials but i am not able to do so...

This is my Code:

```
         Dim Prozess As ProcessStartInfo

        Prozess = New ProcessStartInfo(MyPath\Auftragsstruktur.ps1")
        Prozess.UserName = "MyUserName"
        Prozess.Password = "MyPassword"
        Prozess.Domain = "MyDomain"
        Prozess.UseShellExecute = False
        Prozess.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
        Prozess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal

     Process.Start(Prozess)
```

Comment: I think you're confusing the WorkingDirectory with the actual application to run. You need to give both the application name that will run your script and the arguments to do so in the `New ProcessStartInfo()` constructor. Something like `Prozess = New ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe", "-File ""MyPath\Auftragsstruktur.ps1"")`.

Comment: As for the `WorkingDirectory`, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory) say: _"the WorkingDirectory property must be set if UserName and Password are provided. If the property is not set, the default working directory is %SYSTEMROOT%\system32"_. It must be a path where the alternate user has access to.